# What shape was Apollo 13's orbit in a non-rotating reference frame?

Tags: orbital-mechanics

The classic diagram of Apollo 13's trajectory is a figure-8 (eg. [Wikipedia's illustration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Apollo_13_timeline.svg)).  This is clearly drawn in a reference frame that's rotated to align with the Earth-Moon axis.  What shape would the trajectory be when drawn in a non-rotating Earth-centered reference frame?  My experience with [Kerbal Space Program](https://xkcd.com/1356/) says it would be a near-ellipse, with the "crossover" in the rotating frame being the result of the Moon moving prograde faster than Apollo 13 at that point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a great GIF showing what it looks like (I modified to speed it up), From [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20130118234041/http://www.braeunig.us/apollo/hybrid-profile.htm) archived page:

[image: Non-rotating reference frame path]

You can see that the rotating reference frame view is the same as the inertial. I was trying to find to find enough info to plot it in GMAT to get more data and views, but as of the time of writing I cannot.

Comment: I didn't see this here when I'd posted my answer. Very nice! Also referenced in this [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/21544/12102)

Comment: @uhoh we probably made them at the same time

Comment: Link in this answer appears broken, at least for me..