# Apollo lunar mission trajectory animation

Tags: apollo-program, trajectory

Is there any animation of real trajectory (and real velocity profile) of any of the flown Apollo moon missions?

Something similar to what is shown in the two following links, but using actual data from a flight.
[Lunar Free Return Trajectory Simulation](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/20151/lunar-free-return-trajectory-simulation)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Animation_of_Lunar_Reconnaissance_Orbiter_trajectory_around_Earth.gif

Comment: See this answer for how to plot real data about some parts of the apollo missions: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/58502/3075   Unfortunately not all the historical data have been loaded on SSD system, but maybe upon request, and providing links to data... https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/contact/

Comment: See also my repository where I am collecting all data about Apollo 11: https://github.com/jumpjack/Apollo11LEMdata

Answer (score 2):

Yes!  The good folks at AGI (Makers of STK) simulated the entire [Apollo 11 trajectory](http://agi.com/_agi_custom/apollo/index.html) in STK:
"Based on original NASA documentation, our engineers have built a high-fidelity, eight-day digital mission in Systems Tool Kit (STK). They modeled precise trajectories using STK Astrogator"

The web site has tutorials on how to do some of the simulation using STK/Astrogator (paid software unless you are a student).

I've talked to one of the guys who did it, and they ran into some interesting challenges, like typos, in the original record.  There would be entries in long tables that were nonsensical given the rest of the table, for instance.

Comment: the link is broken