# Apollo 11 trajectory logs

Tags: apollo-program, apollo-11

is there any place where to download the log files of the entire Apollo 11 mission? I want to rebuild it in Matlab and I'd use it as reference.

I've seen that there is [AGI's reconstruition with STK](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/40066/apollo-lunar-mission-trajectory-animation), but I'd prefer some text files (I have no access to STK)

Thanks!

EDIT: for those of you who are also interested: I've found full ascent data in this post-flight report.

https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap10fj/pdf/as-505-postflight-trajectory.pdf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If I wanted to reconstruct an entire Apollo mission's crewed spacecraft trajectories, what are the key sources of historical data I'd look for?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/40074/if-i-wanted-to-reconstruct-an-entire-apollo-missions-crewed-spacecraft-trajecto)

Comment: Hi @OrganicMarble thanks but only partially. I wanted to start with a full reference trajectory to be used as benchmark before starting computing stuff by myself.

Comment: There are several questions asking for that traj data. None fully answered yet.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: In the question that @OrganicMarble linked there's quite some information available. The summary is that there is no full trajectory data available. During the mission, NAT data were generated which recorded the position and attitude at various key points in the mission. The trajectory was then estimated. These estimates are presumable in an elusive Volume II of the postflight analysis report, which appears to have been lost to time. Several reconstructions exists based on the NAT data though, but not as raw text files, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Great ascent data!

Comment: yes! now the question becomes how to import it in txt files without hand-made transcriptions. I'm looking for some free OCR apps

Comment: @venom Great find! The scanning quality is quite poor though: more than half of the digit characters have lost continuity due to over-contrast.  If you don't manage to get decent OCR with "self-learning" capability (it would highligth poorly recognizable symbols for manual correction and will add them to its database after manual correction of each symbol, hence it's getting progressively better on next poor stmbol of the same type), you may need to do a lot of manual corrections. There are plenty of "2"s that look like "7"s, washed away bottom of "9"s that might get interpreted as "8"s, etc.

Comment: @venom Those postflight reports presumably existed for all Apollo missions. In the linked answer there's a link for Apollo 17. I haven't found all of them though.